# CSS: Checkbox switch effect works only for the first checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox, switch-statement

I need to make that switching effect working on any single checkbox I click. For example, I'll check the second (styled) checkbox, it will automatically switch and all others will stay unaffected. Thx very much for help.

https://jsfiddle.net/99asehku/

HTML:

```
    <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div><br><br>
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div><br><br>
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch1" class="onoffswitch-checkbox1" id="myonoffswitch1" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label1" for="myonoffswitch1">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner1"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch1"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 58px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 10px; padding: 0; line-height: 10px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ANO";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "NE";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 10px; margin: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 44px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of commenting out your JSFiddle link as you've intentionally gone around Stack Overflow's ***JSFiddle links must be accompanied by code*** warning by placing the link within a code block. I've also voted to close this question as you've provided no code in the body of the question itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't translated that error message for myself and I urgently needed to get any hint for solution of this prob. I'l be glad to see cleared that negative reputation. Thx

Comment: Much better. I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all id must be unique. Don't use same id for different element.

And make `for` for all different.

```css
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 58px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 10px; padding: 0; line-height: 10px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ANO";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "NE";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 10px; margin: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 44px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div><br><br>
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch1" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch1">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div><br><br>
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch2">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @FilipCZ glad to help. You can accept only one answer. not multiple.

Answer (score 0):

You should differentiate their id and ids should be same as label 'for' attribute:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch1" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch1">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch1" class="onoffswitch-checkbox1" id="myonoffswitch2" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label1" for="myonoffswitch2">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner1"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch1"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Sharing updated fiddle please check:
https://jsfiddle.net/anujAdmin/9w413j0k/

Answer (score -1):

You have to give to each checkbox switch a name and id unique.

Look at this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99asehku/1/); the last one has its own id and name, while the second has the same id and name of the first. (Of course the css code must be repeated or rules modified to apply for each new id)

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Perfect silviagreen, I'm also very pleased you helped me.